# Volume preserving maps between Riemann spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume, riemann-surfaces

It's well-known that for a Riemann sphere $S$, $Aut(S)\simeq PSL(2,\mathbb C)$. If we equip two volume forms $\omega_1,\omega_2$ on $S$, then the volume preserving isomorphism forms a subgroup of $Aut(S)$. Is there a classification about these subgroups? In particular, I am very concerned about whether there is a complex structure on these volume-preserving isomorphism groups.

For a easier case, if $\omega_1=\omega_2$, what can we say about the volume presering automorphisms?

Comment: The group of volume-preserving (in this case, the volume is just the surface-area under the $2D$ metric) automorphisms of the Riemann sphere is just the group of $3D$ rotations, $SO(3)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group
We can however make volume-preserving transformations that do not respect the Complex structure, those are infinitesimally generated by vector fields with vanishing divergence.

Comment: Thanks. When the metric is constant-curvature, the volume-preserving autmomorphisms are indeed $SO(3)$. As a 3-dimensional Lie group, there is no complex structure on $SO(3)$. The more difficult case arise when the metric is arbitrary.

Comment: When the metric is arbitrary, you expect no automorphisms (other than the identity) at all!

Comment: The terms _isomorphism_ and _automorphism_ are, it appears, being used respectively to mean _diffeomorphism_ and _biholomorphism_. If that's right, care is needed to clarify "volume preserving isomorphism forms a subgroup of [automorphisms]", since the group of diffeomorphisms preserving volume forms is infinite-dimensional while the biholomorphism group is finite-dimensional.